# Proper statistical test for trends in time series data

Tags: r, time-series, arima, generalized-additive-model, trend

I have very simple data containing the proportion of daily surgical procedure cancellations (due to equipment/material shortages, case overflows, patient absconded, etc) over a 6-month period. I would simply like to test if there is any trend in these data.

After looking through CV and elsewhere, I initially thought of using the t-test for linear trend and the Mann-Kendall Test (MK) test for monotonic trends. There is also the augmented Dickey-Fuller test which tests the null hypothesis that the series is non-stationary.

However there is good reason to assume that the data are correlated/autoregressive to some degree (i.e., a blood shortage or equipment malfunction may last a few days, or patient spillover). I know that an ARIMA model can account for autocorrelation, but from my understanding is that ARIMA modeling is used more for forecasting rather than testing for trends.

I do not often work with time-series data often so I am a bit outside my purview. The quantity of information on the internet is not exchangeable with expertise. I want to make sure I do good science, and not arrogant enough to think I can do this on my own.

**Put bluntly, what would be the appropriate statistical test to test if there is any trend in these data?**

Example data and figure are below. I am working in the R language.

---

```
datedf <- data.frame(date = seq.Date(from = as.Date("01/01/22", "%m/%d/%y"), 
                                     to = as.Date("05/07/22", "%m/%d/%y"), 
                                     by = "day"),
                     prop = c(0.17, 0.06, 0.29, 0.18, 0.4, 0.23, 0.2, 0.27, 0.33, 0.3, 0.2, 
                              0.19, 0.43, 0.25, 0.19, 0.29, 0.23, 0.23, 0.04, 0.29, 0.35, 0.23, 
                              0.24, 0.19, 0.12, 0.33, 0.35, 0.27, 0.19, 0.26, 0.25, 0.16, 0.38, 
                              0.29, 0.19, 0.13, 0.15, 0.22, 0.26, 0.12, 0.26, 0.27, 0.13, 0.28, 
                              0.28, 0.23, 0.1, 0.35, 0.19, 0.3, 0.3, 0.55, 0.32, 0.26, 0.48, 
                              0.48, 0.37, 0.07, 0.26, 0.28, 0.55, 0.21, 0.26, 0.33, 0.38, 0.41, 
                              0.29, 0.15, 0.17, 0.29, 0.32, 0.27, 0.53, 0.38, 0.48, 0.32, 0.29, 
                              0.17, 0.52, 0.27, 0.41, 0.62, 0.37, 0.35, 0.19, 0.29, 0.21, 0.3, 
                              0.3, 0.33, 0.43, 0.38, 0.5, 0.3, 0.11, 0.43, 0, 0.25, 0.21, 0.23, 
                              0.25, 0.39, 0.29, 0.13, 0.2, 0.19, 0.44, 0.22, 0.29, 0.17, 0.17, 
                              0.18, 0.14, 0.24, 0.14, 0.15, 0.24, 0.15, 0.14, 0.21, 0.27, 0.3, 
                              0.28, 0.19, 0.14, 0.18, 0.12))
plot(datedf, type = "l", ylim = c(0,1), ylab = "Proportion", frame = FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: I think a Generalized Additive Model (GAM) is what you need. Check out the mgcv package in R.